# Having problems installing Krita, unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa, krita

```
sudo apt-get install krita
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 krita : Depends: calligra-libs (= 1:2.8.5-0ubuntu6~ubuntu14.04~ppa1) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libkdcraw23 but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libkdeui5 but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libkfile4 but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libkio5 but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libopencolorio1 but it is not installable
         Depends: libpoppler-qt4-4 (>= 0.20.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

sudo apt-get update
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise InRelease
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                             
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free amd64 Packages               
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg [72 B]                      
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release [11.9 kB]                       
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Hit http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free i386 Packages                
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages [14 B]              
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                       
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Sources                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                       
Get:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg [316 B]             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                       
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam amd64 Packages         
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-en_US            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-en               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                           
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Get:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release [15.1 kB]               
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en           
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages             
Get:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en [4,606 B]
Get:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages [13.8 kB]          
Get:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages [13.8 kB]     
Get:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en [4,824 B]    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en            
Ign http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Translation-en_US               
Ign http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Translation-en                  
Fetched 64.5 kB in 6s (10.2 kB/s)                                              
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'universe/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Quite an Ubuntu noob, first time I have to deal with something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the `restricted` and `universe` repositories are enabled. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `software-properties-gtk` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Under `Ubuntu Software` tab, enable all the repositories.

[image]

The [preferred](https://krita.org/download/krita-desktop/) way of installing `krita` is by enabling the following PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install krita
```

Note that previous versions of `krita` must be uninstalled.

Comment: Well, that's odd. I already had universe and multiverse enabled, only thing I didn't was source code. I thought "What the heck", tried it, and it works.

Comment: Greeeaaat, now I'm getting "Essential application components could not be found. This might be an installation issue."

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. Tried 2 things:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
```

&

```
sude aptitude install kdelibs-bin kdelibs5-data kdelibs5-plugins
```

Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try to do before installing :

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

It worked for me